# What does fn mean when used in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I saw a fn use in raphael, which is a javascript lab.

```
Raphael.fn.g.piechart = function (cx, cy, r, values, opts) {
  // blah...blah
}
```

it extend raphael, so people can uses like r = Raphael; r.g.piechart.

I search google and have nothing seem to be clear my mind. hope you help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fn` is used for **[adding your own methods to the canvas](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#plugins-canvas)**.

Any methods you add to `fn` will work on the canvas. This is in contrast to methods that would work on **[for example an element](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#plugins-elements)** ( for which you would use `el`).

Since extending the `fn` object will act on the canvas, you must add your custom methods **before creating your Raphael instance** (this is not true if you are extending the `el` of an element).

For example, from the documentation:

```
  // Extend Raphael fn object by adding methods to it:
Raphael.fn.arrow = function (x1, y1, x2, y2, size) {
    return this.path( ... );
}; 
  // or add namespaces to it:
Raphael.fn.mystuff = {
    arrow: function () {…},
    star: function () {…},
    // etc…
};

  // Now when you create a Raphael instance, your custom
  // methods are available.
var paper = Raphael(10, 10, 630, 480);

  // Using custom methods:
paper.arrow(10, 10, 30, 30, 5).attr({fill: "#f00"});

  // Using name spaced custom methods
paper.mystuff.arrow();
paper.mystuff.star();
```

---

**Update (thanks AleksandraKos):**

Note that, [namespaced plugins was removed in Raphael 2.0](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.fn)

Comment: Been scouring SO for a way to extend the Raphael object with custom shapes and your comment helped me do it. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that the ability to create namespaced plugins (Raphael.fn.namespace.plugin) was removed in Raphael 2.0, so e.g. paper.mystuff.arrow() will lack the Raphael object and won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Initially it's just an empty object created along with `Raphael`, it's literally just:

```
Raphael.fn = {};
```

[It's a common place for plugins to be stored](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#plugins-canvas), and they're called from there when a new instance is created.

Comment: Yup, line 109 of [ **the uncompressed version** ](http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/raw/master/raphael.js) ==> `R.fn = {};`, and the last line is essentially `Raphael = R`. It look like line 1801 in the function `create()` (which is used to help make the Raphael instance on line 19 ==> `return create[apply](R, arguments);` ) checks for plugins `plugins.call(container, container, R.fn);`

Answer (score 2):

Its short for function.

Its used as a namespace which Raphael stores all its functions under, which automatically allows you apply these functions to a paper object.

You can also extend the functionally of Raphael by adding functions to it.

This is similar to how jQuery's `$.fn` works.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Conner how is this less of an answer than some of the others in this thread?

Comment: That was a canned comment from the beta review system. It doesn't show the other answers.

Comment: @Petah Go review the accepted answer. Compare to yours. Yours is not a quality answer. Your answer doesn't describe why it is short for function or why that information is helpful. Can you add more? This answer just leads to more questions in the reader's mind.

Comment: @LeeLouviere which I agree my answer was crap, my point to Conner was that other answers where just as crap but mine was singled out. Either way I have updated my answer.

Comment: You were singled out by the Review system, not @Conner. In the review system, the reviewer doesn't have access to all answers, just the answer they're shown to review (as well as the question). So you weren't singled out by Conner. On the other hand, it's good that you updated your answer. This answer is far more helpful and will answer most of the questions that a reader will have.

Answer (score 2):

In your own JS code It can be whatever you want - it's not a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), it doesn't have any special meaning, so you can name  variable or method `fn` just like you can use names like `foo` or `myVariable`. In jQuery, for example, `jQuery.fn === jQuery.prototype` (a shortcut for plugin authors).

Answer (score 1):

`fn` is nothing special in JavaScript. It's just the name of a property Raphael uses. See http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special with fn in JavaScript.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.